# Are there any ways for CSS values respond to the window width other than @media screen?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, addition

I was wondering if there are better and more efficient ways for CSS values to respond to the window's width? For example, a large image is positioned in the top right corner when the window is big, but as you scale down the page, the large image gets smaller as it begins to shift of the bottom left corner of the window. A different way to look at it is: 1000px wide screen = `top:0;` so, it'll be set up in a way so that for every 1px the screen size decreases, a value of 1px is added to `top`. It's sort of like REM and typography.

Thoughts / ideas? I'm also looking for a CSS-only solution if possible.

Comment: You can use percentages in the `width:` property.

Comment: Right, but what I am asking is how a 'top' value can increase when the width of a page changes? The 'top' only responds to a vertical change made by the window, not horizontal. I'm looking for a way to do this: decrease width of page = increase value of 'top'.

Comment: ``$(window).width();`` and ``$(window).height();``

Comment: Ah, interesting. Knitevision, would you mind doing a quick demonstration using jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a `percent` value of width.
For example, if you want it to scale the big photo to the distance it has with the bottom of the browser you can use something like:

```
#photo{
    bottom:60%;
    width:50%;
}
```

That way you will always have the same ratios in your window. Ofcourse, to make that happen you have to define a `positiom:relative` container with full width.

Comment: How about for a case like, for example, for every 1% increase in width of the browser window, a div's top value increases by 2px; however, if the browser window decreases by 1%, the div's top value decreases by 2px -- Perhaps a solution where it can be applied to the height of a image, size of font-size, etc?

Comment: It is all bout the container. For example, if you have a right sidebar container with a full height containing the "topDiv", with every change of the height of the window, the height of the container will change too. So the "topDiv" which has a percent value height will change accordingly.

Comment: Now for the font size, you can always use em instead of px, therefore you can have a more responsive feel of the font-size.

Comment: Oh I see, so what you're telling me is that each value (for example, width vs. font-size) all very when it comes to responding to the browser window's width and height? I thought there was some type of magical attribute / command that can universally add / subtract values, but I guess one can only dream of it :)

Comment: You can still use `em` instead of `px` to measure the height,width, and pretty much everything which is a way to measure the dimensions of your elements depending from the size of their containers. It is pretty bad for your responsiveness later ofc. Please give thumbs up if you think you earned something from the answer.

Comment: Yes! Although I find your commends very helpful, would you mind demonstrating the div and font-size method on jsfiddle? I'm having bit trouble comprehending what you're suggesting... I have set up a jsfiddle for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/55L9cq81/2/

Answer (score 1):

You could use viewport units for this

### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55L9cq81/1/)** (Resize window)

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Comment: Interesting... But what if for every 1px increase in the browser windows width increase the margin-top by 5px?

Comment: increase the value of margin-top?

Comment: yup. so for example, if the browser's width is 1000px the div's margin-top is 500px. but if the browser's width is 500px, the div's margin-top makes it way to becoming 1000px. So as the browser's window got smaller and smaller (width:1000px -> width:500px), the div gradually moved lower and lower (margin-top:500px -> margin-top:1000px)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale image size according to parent element's width, use this trick:
http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

This way the image will scale proportionally to the width of parent element.

Regarding image position, it is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve with

> top right corner when the window is big, but as you scale down the
>   page, the large image gets smaller as it begins to shift of the bottom
>   left corner.

You can not get the `top` value to change depending on parent element's width, however you can use the same `padding` trick to position the image. Quick example below. The `padding-bottom` value depends on width of the parent element.

```
        #outer
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding-bottom: 50%;
            border: 1px dashed red;
        }

        #inner
        {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px dashed blue;
        }

    </style>


    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
may be this can help:

document.getElementById("img").style.width = window.innerWidth*3/4;// 60% of window
console.log(window.innerWidth*3/4,window.innerWidth);
document.getElementById("img").style.bottom = window.innerWidth/2;// 50% of window
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look? I'm not sure to as how I can incorporate your code and apply it to the image... http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/Lb5qc8a8/

Comment: in your fiddle you should be using getElementsByTagName.